# "Safely Remove Hardware" icon keeps reverting to "Only show notifications"

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

I have the 'Safely Remove Hardware' tray icon set to 'Show icon and notifications' to save a mouse click when removing a USB device but every few weeks the setting reverts to 'Only show notifications'. Does anyone know what causes this and/or how I can prevent it?

I'm using Windows 7 SP1 64bit with a fairly bare installation (the machine hosts a set of virtual machines that I use to do my work).

Thanks!